# Top navbar not updated when login session is invalidated

Tags: bug, login, authentication, session

**tl;dr** *When editing existing post after your session has been invalidated in the background, editor itself reflects the fact that user has been logged-off, but top navbar remains unchanged and still displays user info*.

---

### Steps to reproduce

1. Login to any site. Find any post
2. Open another tab. Click *Current Community* icon (last) in navbar. Click *log out* link
3. Go back to the first tab and click *Edit* to start editing question or any answer

### Expected behavior

1. Editor detects *not-logged-in* state and displays "Your edit (...) in queue (...) peer reviewed"
2. Top navbar detects *not-logged-in* state and displays *Log In* and *Sign Up* buttons

### Actual behavior

1. Editor detects *not-logged-in* state and displays "Your edit (...) in queue" (correct)
2. Top navbar still displays user icon, reputation, badges, etc. (**incorrect**)

### Screenshot

[image]

### Environment:

- Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.50 (64-bit)
- Windows 10 Pro / 10.0.19042 Build 19042